# Using which technique does facebook show images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

As we all have seen that when we click on an image thumb in Facebook, it loads up full image in a overlay. I was just curious to find out out exactly what is this tool.

As far as I understand it is clearly not an using any "jQuery modal" to show image, as you can see the overlay takes up screen and scroll-bars are adjusted according to size of overlay but not the page itself, which is not in case of jQuery modals. I also looked up some modals like [Eric martin's Simple modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) but no luck.

Does anybody know any plugin which can achieve this Facebook like effect?

Comment: why dont you try fancybox? http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: thanks for suggesting fancybox, I was using Eric Martin's Simple modal, which was my favorite till now, but now its fancybox. It is exactly doing what is required.

Comment: @IoQ Sounds like you should post your Fancybox as a suggestion so it can be accepted as it meets the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I expect Facebook have written their own client-side libraries for doing things, rather than using out-of-the-box plugins like jQuery modals.

Just by observing the behaviour I would expect their script

(a) checks the size of the widow (as popups will scale down to fill the viewport), then
(b) checks the size of the image itself

... and, after leaving room for comments and ads / etc, figures out exactly what size to set the containing div for the overlay. The image itself is then scaled to fit within the available space.

Regarding having scrollbars inside the overlay itself, this can be achieved on any element with a fixed size (i.e. set height / width) using the css `overflow: auto;`. Any block element with that style will display scrollbars if the content is larger than the dimensions of the element.